# Can I split extjs regions into sub-regions?

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, region

I currently have this:

```
  Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'HeaderPanel',
                region: 'north'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'MainMenuPanel',
                flex: 1,
                region: 'west',
                split: false
            },
            {
                xtype: 'AccordionTreePanel',
                flex: 1,
                region: 'west',
                split: false
            },
            {
                xtype: 'ContentTabPanel',
                flex: 3,
                region: 'center'
            }
        ]
    });
```

I would like for the "HeaderPanel" to be divided into subregions. Something similar to this:

```
 {
     xtype: 'HeaderPanel',
     region: 'north',
     items: [
           {
               xtype: 'LeftHeaderPanel',
               region: 'west'
           },
           {
               xtype: 'RightHeaderPanel',
               region: 'center',
           },
     ]
 },
```

Is there something I can do here? Or do I need to customize my layout using something different?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You only need to set `layout:'border'` in the second chunk of the code after `region:'north'` and it should work.

It is border layout nested in border layout in fact. However, you should think if you really need all the functionality of border layout in the inner north region. You can perhaps go with lighter `hbox` layout.

Comment: As soon as I add `layout: 'border'`, nothing seems to load on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using your examples and Saki's comment you should have something like the following. We assume that the xtypes you have used in your example code are defined by you. Otherwise you will get errors.

```
Ext.applyIf(me, {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'HeaderPanel', //xtype: 'container'
            region: 'north',
            layout: 'border',
            flex: 1, //or height: 150,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'LeftHeaderPanel',
                    region: 'west',
                    flex: 1, // or width: 200
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'RightHeaderPanel',
                    region: 'center'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'MainMenuPanel',
            flex: 1,
            region: 'west',
            width: 125,
            split: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'AccordionTreePanel',
            flex: 1,
            region: 'west',
            split: false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'ContentTabPanel',
            flex: 3,
            region: 'center'
        }
    ]
});
```

Edit: Removed hanging commas from the example.

Comment: In your example, say I did not need to have the "HeaderPanel" (it doesn't have anything in particular besides the two panels within), which xtype should I use?

Comment: @Rail24 You could use xtype: 'container' which  is the "lightest" class you can have that implements layout.

Comment: For some reason the `layout: 'border'` option prevents anything from loading, whenever I include it.

Comment: Sorry, I failed you. :)  Whenever you are using the border layout, you must apply either height or width values to panels that are NOT center.  Any panel that is region east or west must have either flex or width values. Any panel that is region north or south must have either flex or height values.  I have corrected my code above to reflect this.